# datetime не найден пишет

Tags: python

```
import datetime
import datetime as dt #писал и без import datetime as dt
class knigi():    
    y1=datetime.datetime.today()

    def __init__(self, kniga, name, god):
        """создание книги"""
        self.kniga = kniga
        self.name = name
        self.god = datetime.date(god)

    def gody(self):
        print((y1-self.god).year)

    def days(self):
        print((y1-self.god).day)
```

Comment: правильный импорт модуля ```import datetime```

Comment: не понял к чему это

Comment: тип написать ее внутрь класса имеешь ввиду ?

Comment: вот так ``правильно``, а вот так ``Неправильно``

Comment: Большие и маленькие буквы - это разное, это важно.

Answer (score 3):

вы неправильно импортировали библиотеку

Вместо:

```
import Datetime
```

надо

```
import datetime
```

Comment: ну или же можно `import datetime as dt`

Comment: спасибо, ошибка исчезла при запуске, но при вводе данных типа так k1= knigi('Garry', 'Lencon', (2020, 11, 13)) все равно пишет что datetime не найден, я подправил код можете посмотреть ?

Comment: щяс пересмотрю ваш код

Comment: попробуйте написать import datetime as dt но не убирайте import datetime

Comment: если ошибка не исчезнет то скорее всего ошибка не в этой части кода

Comment: не в этой части кода